# Add icon+text in PagerSlidingTab

Tags: android, pagerslidingtabstrip

I implemented Astuetz' PagerSlidingTabStrip for Text as Tab. But I want to have both icons and text. I understand from this [link](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip/issues/18) that Astuetz' can have either text or iocn. Can I have any custom layout for this? Also I want the tabs to start from center and the underline indicator to be center fixed.

```html
MainActivity

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
 

 private PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs;
 private ViewPager pager;
 private MyPagerAdapter adapter;

 
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  
  tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
  pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
  adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

  pager.setAdapter(adapter);
  
  final int pageMargin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 4, getResources()
    .getDisplayMetrics());
  pager.setPageMargin(pageMargin);

  tabs.setViewPager(pager);

  
 }
 public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

  private final String[] TITLES = { "Contact", "Home"};
  //private final int[] ICONS = { R.drawable.ic_contact, R.drawable.ic_home};

  public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
   super(fm);
  }

  @Override
  public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
   return TITLES[position];
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
   return TITLES.length;
  }

  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int position) {
   return SuperAwesomeCardFragment.newInstance(position);
  }

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the method shows in the library you can not do it without modifying the code. You need to fork for the same .
As the below method shows-

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabCount; i++) {

        if (pager.getAdapter() instanceof IconTabProvider) {
            addIconTab(i, ((IconTabProvider) pager.getAdapter()).getPageIconResId(i));
        } else {
            addTextTab(i, pager.getAdapter().getPageTitle(i).toString());
        }

    }
```

You can have only one either the texts or the icons at a time.
I will suggest you to use the `TabLayout` from design support library. You can use `setCustomView` method to set custom view in tabs.

Comment: Can you give me any sample link?

Comment: And how to make the indicator fixed at center?